# Polling SQS message from container in EC2 instance - EC2 Instance IAM Role vs ECS Task Role

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-kms

I  am trying to poll SQS messages from a spring boot app running on a container in an EC2 instance. Both the consumer and SQS queue are on the same AWS account.
The messages are encrypted with a KMS key, so I need to create a "km:Decrypt" rule, otherwise, I'm always getting this same message:

> com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The ciphertext
> refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in
> this region, or you are not allowed to access

To allow decryption, I can either:

1. create the rule directly in the KMS key policy -> I don't want to do this due to security reasons
2. create the rule at the EC2 Instance IAM Role level -> I wanted to avoid this because I have other containers running in the same EC2 instance
3. create the rule at the ECS Task role level -> preferred option

The 3rd option is already in place, but the problem is that the spring boot request is always using the EC2 Instance IAM Role (terraform-20210318145009433200000002), as seen in CloudTrail, instead of the ECS Task role:

[image]

How can I make it use the ECS Task role?

Comment: What task role? Are you using AWS ECS? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, ECS task role

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to block access to the credentials that are supplied to the Amazon EC2 instance profile using one of these methods:

1. Setting the environment variable `ECS_AWSVPC_BLOCK_IMDS` to true.
2. Running the following command:

```
sudo yum install -y iptables-services; sudo iptables --insert DOCKER-USER 1 --in-interface docker+ --destination 169.254.169.254/32 --jump DROP
```

It depends on the ECS task definition.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#task-iam-role-considerations